# Azure ml deployment : os.makedir() in score.py init() function, throws permission error during deployment

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-machine-learning-service

I have to create files and directories in order to perform prediction of my custom model. here is my init function and deployment logs :

```
import os

inputs_root = "inputs"
outputs_root = "outputs"

def init():
    if not os.path.exists(inputs_root):
        os.mkdir(inputs_root)
    if not os.path.exists(outputs_root):
        os.mkdir(outputs_root)
```

It throws following error which can be seen from the deployment logs as follows :

```
2023-04-13 14:10:52,736 E [68] azmlinfsrv - Encountered Exception Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda/envs/amlenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/server/user_script.py", line 117, in invoke_init
    self._user_init()
  File "/var/azureml-app/avaj1870/src/score.py", line 71, in init
    os.mkdir(inputs_root)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'inputs'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda/envs/amlenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/server/aml_blueprint.py", line 111, in setup
    self.user_script.invoke_init()
  File "/opt/miniconda/envs/amlenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml_inference_server_http/server/user_script.py", line 119, in invoke_init
    raise UserScriptException(ex) from ex
azureml_inference_server_http.server.user_script.UserScriptException: Caught an unhandled exception from the user script
```

I tried to create folder in azure  online endpoint, it throwed permission exception.

Comment: I tried this in my Azure ML studio notebook and was able to create input and output directory  , Refer the path here - https://i.imgur.com/FrnJbkh.png

Comment: Where are you running this script in Azure ML?

Comment: Original script is more complicated, this score.py is simplified version to describe problem. Model is not accepting regular data types, I have to go into huge coding effort if I can't open these directories.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error, but i did not got any error it's just worked fine.
Here is the result, I logged the path.
[image]

Here is the code in my `__init__.py` script.

```
import  os
import  logging
import  json
import  numpy
import  joblib

inputs_root = "./inputs"
outputs_root = "./outputs"

def  init():
    if  not  os.path.exists(inputs_root):
        os.mkdir(inputs_root)
    if  not  os.path.exists(outputs_root):
        os.mkdir(outputs_root)
        
global  model
model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv("AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"), "model/sklearn_regression_model.pkl")
model = joblib.load(model_path)
logging.info(os.path.abspath(inputs_root))
logging.info(os.path.abspath(outputs_root))
logging.info("Init complete")
```

Here I used `inputs_root = "./inputs"` instead
of  `inputs_root = "inputs"`.
But both ways worked for me, I am asking you to try adding,
`inputs_root = "./inputs"` and  `outputs_root = "./outputs"`.

Comment: Can you share which environment did you used? I am using environment created from dockerfile.